# Haskell missing parentheses compiles but enters infinite loop

Tags: haskell, syntax, parentheses

I have a case where a Haskell missing parentheses compiles fine but enters an infinite loop. Here is my code with the working version commented out:

```
$ cat main.hs
fib :: Int -> Int
fib 0 = 1
fib 1 = 1
fib n =
  let
    fib_n_minus_2 = fib n-2
    -- fib_n_minus_2 = fib (n-2)
    fib_n_minus_1 = fib (n-1)
  in
    fib_n_minus_2+
    fib_n_minus_1

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ show $ fib 7
```

When I compile it everything goes fine, but when I run the resulting program it gets stuck. Why is that? I imagine the compiler parses `fib n`,
then goes on to see `-2 fib_n_minus_1` where it should stop and issue an error, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
fib_n_minus_2 = fib n-2
```

means

```
fib_n_minus_2 = (fib n)-2
```

and not

```
fib_n_minus_2 = fib (n-2)
```

Note that `(fib n)-2` is a perfectly valid expression.

This is not parsed as `(fib n) -2 fib_n_minus1 ...` since `fib_n_minus1 ...` starts on the next line and is indented the exact same amount as the previous one, so it's the next *binding* for the `let` construct.

Indeed, you can pretend that, before real parsing starts, indentation is used to insert explicit braces around the bindings, and semicolons between them, as follows:

```
 let {
    fib_n_minus_2 = fib n-2 ;
    -- fib_n_minus_2 = fib (n-2)
    fib_n_minus_1 = fib (n-1)
    }
  in
    fib_n_minus_2+
    fib_n_minus_1
```

In the `in` section of `let` there can be only one *expression*, so the indentation rule does not apply, and those two lines are parsed as one expression, `fib_n_minus_2 + fib_n_minus_1`.

In conclusion, your code is calling itself without decreasing the argument `n`, thus causing the infinite recursion.